# css position question: layers with z-index?

Tags: jquery, css, position

hey guys,
i have a probably rather simpel problem:

my website has two layers:

1) a drag&drop navigation on top which should be positioned absolute, so scrolling doesn't affect the bars.

2) a content area in the back behind the navigation which should be scrollable.

you can see what i mean right here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pghqv/

however now, i cannot click links in my content-area in the back. any ideas or solutions how i can still have the same position result and the links in the back are working?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your demo the only reason you can't click the content behind the header is *because it's behind the <del>header</del> `#navigation` div*. If you move it from behind the <del>header</del> `#navigation` div, with, for example, `margin-top: 200px;` then it works: [JS fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Pghqv/2/).

---

**Edited** with regard to the need for the solution to be dynamic, and to the jQuery tag:

If the height of the `#navigation` div isn't known in advance, then the following jQuery can be used instead of a concrete `css` declaration in the stylesheet:

```
$('#page-wrap').css('margin-top',$('#navigation').outerHeight());
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Pghqv/4/).

Comment: what do you mean with behind the header? i don't even have a header.

Comment: @user239831: ah, my apologies: I meant the `div` with an `id` of 'navigation'.

Comment: oh yeah, but is there no other way to make that work. my navigation is dynamic so it could be like 1000px high as well.

Comment: @user239831: sure, since you have a jQuery tag I've edited the answer (with a demo) to offer a jQuery solution.

Comment: nice solution, however that works exactly against my page layout. the navigation should lie over the content area and the contentarea should not move it's position anywhere underneath the navigation. i just thought there might be a simpel solution and i'm doing anything wrong in my css.

Comment: @user239831: Not that I can see, no; sorry. =/